# Searching route through many city

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ride` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `to` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `route_through` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_ride` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I need search `ride`:

```
SELECT * FROM ride WHERE from=$from and to=$to
```

How to search if I have city in `route_through`?

For example:

**`ride` table:**

`id` = 1

`from` = Paris

`to` = London

**`route_through` table:**

`id` = 1

`id_ride` = 1

`city` = 'Madrid'

**Search in form:**

Now I set in form this city: `from` - Madrid `to` London. This should return `ride` with `id` = 1

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

use a JOIN

```
SELECT * 
FROM ride r inner join route_through rt on r.id = rt.id
WHERE from=$from and to=$to
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a `ride` can have multiple `route_through` records, in which case this query will return multiple rows containing the **same** ride, but each with a **different** route_through

Comment: @thaJeztah then he can add in additional logic.

Comment: Agreed, just placed my comment to notify the OP of the consequences as he clearly isn't very experienced. If only the *names* of the `route_through` is required, a simple `GROUP_CONCAT()` may be sufficient